# Validate form in different controller action symfony

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a controller action that returns a form to the view. When the form is submitted, the validation of this form needs to be done in a different action than the action returning the form.

This is a sample of the action that returns the form

```
 /**
     * @Route("/AjaxAddQuestionForm/{section}")
     * @Template
     * @ParamConverter("section", class="AppBundle:Section")
     */
    public function ajaxAddQuestionFormAction(Request $request, $section)
    {
        $question = new Question();
        $question->setSection($section);
        $addQuestionForm = $this->createForm(new AddQuestionType(), $question);

        return array(
            'section' => $section,
            'addAjaxQuestionForm' => $addQuestionForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

And this is the action in which I am currently trying to get the validation to work.

```
 /**
     * @Route("/edit/{form}")
     * @Template()
     * @ParamConverter("form", class="AppBundle:Form")
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, $form)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        (...)

         $questionForm = new Question();
         $addQuestionForm = $this->createForm(new AddQuestionType(), $questionForm);


        $addQuestionForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($addQuestionForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($questionForm);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_form_edit', array('form' => $form_id));
            }
(...)
```

The problem is that the validation in the second action is never called. Any idea on how I can get this working?

Comment: Did you set form action to correct route?

Comment: What do you mean by this? How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add form action if you want validate form on other url:

In `ajaxAddQuestionFormAction`:

```
$addQuestionForm = $this->createForm(new AddQuestionType(), $question,
    array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('edit_form')
));
```

edit action route:

```
*@Route("/edit", name="edit_form")
```

Comment: Helped me out a lot with this! Thank you very much.